# Is it true that "Someone" means an important person?

Tags: meaning, spoken-english

If you feel like a someone, what is that mean?

Comment: second definition https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/someone

Answer (score 3):

"Someone" can be used to denote the presence of an unknown, or unnamed person:

> eg "*there is someone at the door*".

It might be helpful to note that the opposite of this definition would be either "*nobody*" or "*no one*":

> "There is nobody at the door".

---

The [second definition of "someone",](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/someone)  which is what your question is about, is "*a person of significance*", or "*someone noteworthy*".

> eg "*One day I'm going to be someone*".

Interestingly, the words "no one" and "nobody" are also used to express that somebody is *not* significant:

> He's a nobody.